# Use a TextView to get a Contact from Address Book

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, contacts

I'm very new to Android Dev and am having issues trying to get an `editText` to pull out one contact. I've created 3 `editText`s that will take a contact each and will send a SMS to the selected contact(s).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIEDH.jpg

I've tried several things that I've found online, but they all crash and I don't really understand what I'm doing.

I know that I have to create a `onClickListener()`:

```
    contact.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub


      } 
    });
```

The other question that I have is, since I need to select one contact per EditText, do I have to copy the same code for the three `EditText`s?

After the contact is selected I would like to display just the name of the contact.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What exactly you mean by **trying to get an editText to pull out one contact** you want to get the text value of it or you want to get the object of editText ?

Comment: I want to tap on one editText and have it open the contacts so I can select one of the contacts, and get the phone number that I need to send the sms, but I want the editText to show just the name of the Contact.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like i did in one of my app (I did this on button click you and use your edittext)
Open The contact

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 Intent intent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,  Contacts.CONTENT_URI);

        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);

            }
        });
```

Then after user select you can get the result in OnActivityResult Method and process the contact uri to load details of contact

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);

  switch (reqCode) {
    case (PICK_CONTACT) :
      if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Uri contactData = data.getData();
        Cursor c =  managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
          String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
          // TODO Fetch other Contact details as you want to use
              Set the name of contact in your editText

        }
      }
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll see if I can implement it. I tried once and it didn't work.